# mouselistener on tableviewer to select row on doubleclick

Tags: java, swt, jface

i want to implement mouse listener on tableviewer and on double-clicking any row of the table, the details of that particular row should be displayed in a popup which also contains a table....

Answer (score 6):

To add a double click listener to a viewer you do the following:

```
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener()
{
            @Override
            public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
                try {

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

});
```

Comment: How can the row values be obtained inside the listener?

Answer (score 3):

```
tableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
        }
    });
```